# ReferenceError : Dispatch is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a Connector, which has mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps functions, and I need to dispatch a action from my main component.

I'm getting an error saying dispatch is not defined when I'm trying to dispatch `fetchPlaces(this.props.user.id)`

`this.props.user.id` has value 1.

I need to get the user id and pass it to fetchPlaces, which intern gets me the places of the user. I'm not sure how to do it.

Connector

```js
const mapStateToProps = function (store) {
    return {
        elements: store.elements.elements,
        places: store.places.places,
        geocode : store.geocode.geocode,
        user : store.user.user
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = function (dispatch) {
    return {
        userAction : dispatch(fetchUser()),
        elementsAction : dispatch(fetchCategories()),
        placesAction: (id) => { dispatch(fetchPlaces(id)) }        
    }
}

class BasicinfoConnector extends React.Component{
  render() {
      console.log(this.props.user);
      if(typeof this.props.user.id != "undefined"){
          return (
              <Basicinfo elements={this.props.elements} places={this.props.places} geocode={this.props.geocode} user={this.props.user}/>
          );
      }
      else{
          return null;
      }
  }
}

export default Redux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BasicinfoConnector);
```

Component :

```js
componentWillMount() {
        console.log(this.props);
        console.log(this.props.user.id);
        dispatch(fetchPlaces(this.props.user.id))
    }
```

Is `placesAction: (id) => { dispatch(fetchPlaces(id)) }` the right syntax of doing it?

**UPDATE**

I changed `componentWillMount` :

```js
componentWillMount() {
        console.log(this.props);
        console.log(this.props.user.id);
        dispatch(this.props.placesAction(this.props.user.id))
    }
```

and mapDispatchToProps :

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = function (dispatch) {
    return {
        userAction: bindActionCreators(fetchUser, dispatch),
        elementsAction: bindActionCreators(fetchUser, dispatch),        
        placesAction: (id) => { dispatch(fetchPlaces(id)) }
    }
}
```

Still have the same error.

Comment: *"I need to dispatch a action from my main component"* You would be calling the corresponding prop for that. E.g. `this.props.placesAction(this.props.user.id)`. The component itself doesn't have access to `dispatch` so trying to call it inside the component will only fail (as you noticed). Btw, you should assign functions to `userAction` and `elementsAction`, *not* call `dispatch` right away.

Comment: So something like `placesAction: (id) => { dispatch(fetchPlaces(id)) }`

Comment: You already have that and that's correct.

Comment: Oki, so I added bindActionCreators, got the reference from https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/89

Comment: @FelixKling Updated the changes, still the error exists. Am I missing anything else?

Comment: As I said, you cannot call `dispatch` in `componentWillMount`. `placesAction` will call `dispatch`.

Comment: you dont need those curlies on placesAction. Not that it has anything to do with your issue;) (id) => dispatch(fetchPlaces(id)) should do fine:)

in componentWillMount, you need to just call this.props.placesAction(someotherProp)

Comment: @thsorens Thanks for the info. :) Right now after removing the dispatch from `componentWillMount`, it gives error saying `TypeError: this.props.placesAction is not a function`

Comment: is is within the <BasicInfo> component that you are trying to do that?

Comment: @thsorens Yes, It is.

Comment: So you need to to either this <Basicinfo ...this.props /> to share all your props down to the next level, or you have to define that prop with <Basicinfo placesAction={(id) => this.props.placesAction(id)} /> to pass it down to the child-component

Comment: @thsorens There you go buddy. You can post this as answer, would help someone.

Comment: Actually `<Basicinfo ...this.props />` did not work, but the other syntax worked. May be because I'm using 0.14.8 react version

Comment: well, i think that might have something to do with the ecmascript-version you are using. Not really sure which version that got available ;)

Comment: Cool. Thank you.. :)

Comment: i had a typo in my comment. I edited the answer, so you can try it that way with the ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the property down to the next level, either by sharing all your props like this:

```
<Basicinfo {...this.props} />
```

or only the particular ones that you want

```
<Basicinfo placesAction={(id) => this.props.placesAction(id)} />
```